# Execlp C Script Error

Tags: c, linux, find, exec

So I have a script that i try to run.
I have this line of code:

```
execlp("find","find","-name",cmdCommands,"-exec","stat","--format","\"%A %s %x %w\"","{} \\;",NULL);
```

That line gives me this error

```
find: missing argument to '-exec'
```

I'm guessing that `"{} \\;"` is the problem. I changed to `"{}","\\;"` but I still get the same error.

What I have to modify to work.

`cmdCommands` is a `char`; I use `execlp` in a child process.

Comment: Also drop the double-backslash. It's also related shell stuff.

Comment: after i remove quotes from "--format" i get this message  : error 'format' undeclared. with only 1 backslash i get this : unkown escape sequence '\;' with no backslash it compiles but i get back to -exec error

Comment: The syntax is: `--format=format-expression` mind the `=`!

Comment: so no i have 'execlp("find","find","-name",cmdCommands,"-exec","stat",--format=,"\"%A %s %x %w\"","{} ;",NULL);' i get 'format undlecared'

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is that you pass the `stat` command and its arguments as different arguments for the `find` command. The `stat` command and all its arguments is a *single* argument to the `find` command.

So change the call to e.g.

```
execlp("find", "find", "-name", cmdCommands, "-exec",
       "stat --format \"%A %s %x %w\" {}", ";", NULL);
```

Comment: ty I don`t have any errors but I have a script in which you introduce commands and receive some response. In my case I use this execlp with a command named myfind <file>. If I want to show the result of execlp how can I do that ?

Comment: if I write in command line find . -name status.c -exec stat --format "%A %s %x %n"  {} \; with or without '.' i get the same result. My problem is that execlp is functional but I want to show it as a printf. something like printf("<execlp result>");

Comment: @user2907139: This is a different issue, so you want to create another question for this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use:

```
  execlp("find", "find", 
    ".", /* Replace by path to search through. */ 
    "-name", cmdCommands, 
    "-exec", "stat", "--format=\"%A %s %x %w\"", "{}", ";", 
    (char*) NULL /* The cast is mandatory to stay portable. */
  );
```

Comment: I used the same as you written and it compiled and runned but as I was saying I want to show the result of execlp like in printf("<your execlp result>");